# How do you exclude records by their specific properties?

Tags: prolog

Say you have a program with

```
book('Hps','Pages','twohundred').
book('Lww','Pages','onehundred').
book('Aff','Pages','onehundred').
book('Jin','Pages','onehundred').
```

`book('Hps','Colour','Black').
book('Lww','Colour','Red').
book('Aff','Colour','Red').
book('Jin','Colour','Black').`

And that you want to find all books which are one hundred pages long, but you want to exclude books which are black, how would you go about it?

I have the following rule

`bookohpnb(X) :-
    book(Y,_,'onehundred'),
    book(Y,_,`

But I can't figure out how to finish it off in a way which will exclude the book results which are black.

I know I could just ask the program to find just red, but the example I have given is a very small portion of a much bigger program, there are many more records in the larger program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been too many years that I am not coding in prolog, so simply forgive me if it doesn't work:

```
bookohpnb(X) :-
    book(Y,_,'onehundred'),
    book(Y,_,C),
    not(C = 'black').
```

Comment: I don't think that one quite works. If it helps, I need to display the shortened book titles (the 'Hps', 'Lww' 'Aff' 'Jin') of the books which are onehundred pages and are not black.  So the first result of a query 'bookohpnb(X).' would be 'Lww' - hit ';' and the next result would be 'Aff'.

Comment: My bad, yes, you're right, that was very helpful - thank you.

Comment: You should, instead of `not`, use `\+`, `\+ C = 'Black'`. This is the same as `C \= 'Black'`. Any way, it is better to use `dif(C, 'Black')`: see the documentation on `dif/2` to figure out more. It is also strange that you leave the second argument of `book/3` a free variable: it would be better to say `book(B, 'Pages', 'onehundred'), book(B, 'Colour', C), dif(C, 'Black').`

Comment: Thanks Boris, as I said it has been too many years I left coding in prolog (20+ years namely), I am rather rusty on the syntax.